# Recover windows after Ubuntu install in new partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Ona computer which initially had Windows 7, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 by creating two new partitions (root and swap).

I now have grub installed but can't seem to get Windows 7 (on another partition) to appear in the Grub menu.

I have tried running `boot-repair` as suggested by answers for other issues of the same sort. I have also tried manually adding the partition to the grub customization files.

Below is partial output from `boot-repair` which indicates I do still have windows 7 and haven't accidentally overwritten it.

At the bottom it indicates it fixed a windows boot issue but still no luck.

Can anyone see any smoking guns in the `boot-repair` log file?

```
Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32776 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *    628,609,024   823,920,639   195,311,616  83 Linux
/dev/sda2             206,848   515,854,335   515,647,488   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         515,854,336   628,609,023   112,754,688   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         823,920,640   831,920,127     7,999,488  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 8019 MB, 8019509248 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 974 cylinders, total 15663104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048    15,663,103    15,661,056   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        392af7fa-8735-4c0d-a0d8-fdfcb1d94b48   ext4       
/dev/sda2        7E6060EC6060AD19                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        F4A82B27A82AE836                       ntfs       Data
/dev/sda4        a4eb0099-6896-4e07-b07e-cb2b3cf485d9   swap       
/dev/sdb1        3223-28B4                              vfat       UBUNTU 14_0
/dev/sr0                                                udf        8930_R9.bc


=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot


Quantity of real Windows: 1
WinSE in sda2
/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ may need repair.
/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/bootmgr may need repair.

*******lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0579]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0579]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev ff)
*******

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
```

Comment: It looks like you overwrote the Windows boot partition. It normally is not shown in Windows. But often is a 100MB NTFS partition with the boot flag. Grub does not use boot flag. If you move boot flag to sda2 using gparted or Windows 'set active' and then run Windows repairs from a Windows repair disk, that will reinstall the missing boot files. Windows does not have to have separate Boot partition unless you want encryption. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec.exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues You cannot fix from Linux. Missing BCD & bootmgr.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for your response. I could see the 100MB boot partition and was careful not to use it when creating the partitions (I used unallocated space). I do now get the error `BOOTMGR is missing` when I boot SDA3.

Comment: You are not showing the 100MB boot partition. That normally contains the bootmgr & /boot/BCD. But you do not need the separate partition just repair to add them or restore from backup bootmgr & BCD. But you must have boot flag on main NTFS partition for repairs to work.